# Meteor unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, meteor

Hello I am new to meteor and I am trying to add the username and password to the database.

```
database = new Meteor.Collection('Database');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.addUser.events ({
        'click .login': function(){
            Items.insert({
                username: $('.username').val()
                password: $('.password').val() <-- error on this line
            });
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

  });
}
```

I dont see any unexpected identifiers but when compiling it says there is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
username: $('.username').val()
```

missing a `,` after `val()` that is causing the *Unexpected Identifier* error.